# WSO2 ESB: Proxy Service - how to use faultsequence

Tags: wso2-esb

I wish all my Proxy Services to log a standard ERROR when the endpoint publishes a soapfault. Setting faultSequence to a valid logging sequence doesn't seem to be doing anything. I know the endpoint is publishing fault responses & the faultlogger sequence is a simply FULL log.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault...> </SOAP-ENV:Fault>

<proxy ... >
   <target faultSequence="faultlogger" endpoint="conf:/myService>
    ...
  </target>
</proxy>
```

How does faultSequence work?

I also tried to use a out, filter + log but wasn't sure what the xpath expression I should use to filter for faults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

faultSequence is executed when there is a technical error (in your xpath for exemple, or can't connect to an address configured in an endpoint)

A SOAPFault is not a technical problem and the out sequence is executed : you can verify response message to find potentials soap faults.

An other solution is to set the property named FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT :

```
<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
```